# New tab opening on launch of chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I launch my Chrome app, a new in a new window opens. This shouldn't happen because
`"manifest version": "2"`
I don't understand why this is happening. Could it be something to do with background.js? This problem occurred long after I did anything with background.js so I don't think that's the issue.

It happens to all my Chrome apps so I don't think it is my code that is the problem.

I version 39 of Chrome running on OS X Yosemite.

It seemed to have happened when I added this

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, char) {
    var a = this.split("");
    a[index] = char;
    return a.join("");
};
```

But I'm not sure how this could effect other chrome apps so that may not be the issue. Other than that I haven't really done anything to any of my apps. I just ran it and it opened along with a new chrome window. I also noticed that when i comment the background.js file, the chrome window doesn't open and nothing happens.

This is background.js of the same that has the above code in main.js.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html',
    {
      id: 'mainWindow',
      state: 'fullscreen'
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: How can we know if we don't see your code?

Comment: It happens to all my Chrome apps so I don't think it is my code that is the problem.

Comment: If it happens to all of your Chrome apps, then surely you can point to at least one of them? I don't know which Chrome apps you're running, so I cannot help with troubleshooting unless you provide enough information so I can try to verify the problem.